# How to set shipping address same as billing address on change shipping address from options magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

i want to set billing address dynamically as per the change of shipping address 
magento 2.
In checkout page "same as shipping" checkbox is there & its also checked still
changing the shipping address from the existing options doesn't set the billing address as per shipping address.

Appreciate your help.